# How to suppress "stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device" in Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, sh, stty, phpunit

I use PHPUnit with Jenkins.
PHPUnit outputs many "stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device." like this

```
[***] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3872195701082406677.sh 
+ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/
PHPUnit 5.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
...
```

What should I do to suppress this message?